# Calculated fields with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fully embrace the separation of concerns provided by the MVC methodology, but have reached something of a roadblock that I would appreciate advice on.
How do you deal with / where should you place the code for fields that are not stored in the DB back-end, but can be directly derived from it?

For example, I may have a model representing a Person. Stored info may include their Date Of Birth. Obviously, I can calculate their current age from this, but wouldn't have it stored in the DB. Now, I want to treat age as a field when accessing the person object (maybe selecting everyone over a certain age) with a Lambda. BUT, if I put the code into the model, am I not breaking the separation of concerns? Even if I do put it there, should it be calculated when the field is accessed via get, or when the object is created? What about changes to the DOB? Should the age reflect the new value immediately, or only when the record is written back?

Let us assume, for the sake of discussion, that the calculation takes a significant time to process, so we want to minimize its use.

I hope the question makes sense!

Comment: A read-only field (one with a `get` and no `set`) on the model seems like the ideal place to put this logic.  Did you try?  Was there an error?

Comment: Yes, and no error. However I don't know how often the various Lambda functions query the get? What if I'm doing a sort and it queries on every comparison? Then, surely, my get function could be called a significant number of times! Also, I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to do it - give separation of concerns. If not "correct" is there a "better"?

Comment: And what's the problem with that?  If the calculation is significant but the result rarely changes then you can cache the resulting value in a private variable, then invalidate that cache any time data elements which affect the calculation are changed.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Age` field will only be displayed/needed on some views it would make sense to have this property on the corresponding view model. You could have a function that will take a `Person` instance and calculate its age. So your controller could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    Person person = GetFromDB(id);
    PersonViewModel viewModel = Map(person);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and inside the `Map` method:

```
public PersonViewModel Map(Person person)
{
    var result = new PersonViewModel();
    result.Age = GetAge(person.Dob);
    ... some other fields
    return result;
}
```

Now the `Age` property will be available to the corresponding view and can be accessed multiple times without recalculation.